# Which curvilinear coordinate systems can I use to describe flat space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

Can I use a coordinate system that has an intrinsic curvature to describe a flat space (such as Minkowski space)?

Say, for example, I wanted to provide coordinates for an infinite flat plane (${E}^{2}$) it seems apparent that I couldn't use spherical coordinates (i.e. longitude and latitude) ***globally*** to do this because they  have an intrinsic constant positive curvature (curve back on themselves), whereas the flat plane has zero curvature.

So, in general relativity, when I have a flat metric, and do a coordinate transformation to another coordinate system, must that coordinate system also be "flat"?  Or, is it true  that  all reasonable coordinate systems are "flat" in an infinitesimal neighbourhood of a given point and that consequently, as the tensor change of coordinate transformations involve only derivatives, the intrinsic curvature of the new coordinate system is irrelevant?

Comment: Hmmm... Any of them? Isn't it what general principle of relativity is about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This characteristic of flat is actually a statement about curvature; it is intuitively clear that the Minkowski (Euclidean) metric has no curvature, but the mathematical statement of flatness is that the Riemann tensor $R_{ijkl} = 0$ everywhere. From this, it should be clear that any coordinate transformation leaves the Riemann tensor invariant if the space is flat, which shows that you can never transform from a flat space to a curved space.

On the other hand, if we start with a curved space we can always choose coordinates such that at a given point $x$, $g_{\mu\nu} (x) = \eta_{\mu\nu} \Rightarrow \Gamma_{\nu\sigma}^{\mu} (x) = 0$. Hence, we can always choose coordinates such that the space looks flat locally. As you note, with such a procedure we should not expect it to work globally in general.

Comment: So @Aaron , If I'm in Minkowski space and choose to transform to a uniformly rotating frame of reference this is:  a) permitted and b) the underlying space still has the same curvature (i.e. 0). Therefore (and this is the thing I really wish to understand),  I can state the Faraday EM two-form F in an inertial frame, move to a uniformly rotating  frame apply  the tensor coordinate transformations to F and obtain the correct form of F despite being in a rotating frame?

Comment: @GeoffreyBryan Yes, that is correct. You can think of this even in the non-relativistic case. One can move from a inertial frame with a particle at rest to a rotating frame of reference by introducing centrifugal forces, which is essentially what the christoffel symbols do in the covariant derivative under a generic coordinate transformation.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for the catch, I've changed it.